# How to get the position of a tap event with zepto

Tags: mobile, jquery, zepto

Is there any way to get the position of a tap event when using zepto? It seems that no screenX screenY are passed in the event object.

Comment: There is no current way to get this information back out.  I have just submitted a pull request to add this into the supplied event.